# Preventing a user from dropping its' own trigger

Tags: oracle

I have created a read only user A in Oracle DB. (who can access schema X but cannot alter anything) Then i am asked to give user A create table privilege on schema X.

However as far as i know, i can either give **create any table** privilege to user A or **create table** privilege. One of them is for creating table on his/her own schema, other one is for creating table on all schemas, which should not be preferred.

So i have given **create any table** privilege to user A and then created a trigger which prevents user A from creating a table on schemas other than X.

HOWEVER,
I needed to create the trigger as user A, and now user A can easily drop that trigger because A is the owner.
Is there any way i can prevent user A from dropping triggers even if he/she's the owner ?

As far as i experienced,user A does not need to have drop any trigger or administer database trigger privileges since trigger is already his/her own.

Is there any workaround for this ? Or should i search for an alternative way to give create table permission on other schemas.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to prevent a user from dropping an object that it owns.

There's also no way to directly allow for user A to create objects in user X's schema, unless you start granting "ANY" privileges.

One possible workaround may be to create a stored procedure in user X's schema that will create objects in user X's schema (execute immediate) and grant EXECUTE privilege on said stored procedure to user A.

So, in this way, user A could do something like:

```
exec create_in_x_schema('create table blah(a number)');
```

And that procedure would just do an execute immediate on the string passed in.

```
A procedure that looks something like:
create or replace procedure create_in_x_schema(doit varchar2)
begin
  execute immediate doit;
end;
/
```

ought to do it.

(Code is untested, but should give you some idea.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course, that procedure should make sure that "doit" is something you allow the user to do. So use DBMS_ASSERT to check the SQL. And add code to confirm that it's one of your allowed options, like "create table". Otherwise, anything X can do, A will be able to do.

Comment: Abslutely correct.  The code I posted above is potentially a big security risk.  It was strictly proof of concept.